# How to allow Telegram bots to read local filesystem

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I am using [Node.JS Telegram Bot API](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api), which is a great framework. But I would like to make my Telegram bot to read a file in a user's local filesystem. Is it possible?

Comment: No, of course not. But they can send your bot a file..

Comment: Yeah, it might works too... But I would have to store the information in a kind of local database. These are sensitive informations like API key. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

you can not read user's local filesystem with telegram bot API. but in the comments you asked is there a way to store bot API key in your local storage? I'm not sure what exactly you want but you can have a database at your server an store all information's you want in it. for example user can send a sensitive info to your bot and then you can store it in tour local storage.

Comment: I don't want to store sensitive data in the cloud :/